# Combo box-and Quotation mark

Tags: c#

I have a combo box that fills with data from a select command:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" select * from m10_NEW where [Unit Description] like '" + tagNameComboBox.Text + "' AND [Frequency] like '31' AND [M10 TYPE] like 'Mechanical' ", con);
```

When the combo box fills with data like such as `Pump's Motor No. 2` I get an error message:

> syntax error ( missing operator) in query expression

The problem is because of the `'` quotation mark

How  can  I fix  this without changing the name of my data?

Comment: use [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2), Or you can just replace '[some data]' with ''[some data]''

Comment: You can Replace it with a DOUBLE single quotation mark. use Pump''s motor instead of Pump's motor.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [SqlParamater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of directly concatenating the SQL string.

In addition to solving your problem - This is also a security improvement since it prevents SQL Injection attacks.